# Why wont my phaser script output the map I created?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Here is my code: https://replit.com/@JackF99/test-2d-array
(Bug is in script.js)

This code is supposed to output the game screen with the map.

```
let mapArr;
let drawX=0;
let drawY=0;
//map is declared as variable in map.js
class gameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    //Constructor with config var declared at bottom
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }
    //Preload aspects for gameScene 
    preload() {
        //Preloading images
        this.load.atlas("player", "assets/temp.png");
        this.load.image("spike", "assets/spike.png");

        this.load.image("floor", "assets/floor.png");
        this.load.image("wallLeft", "assets/wallLeft.png");
        this.load.image("wallRight", "assets/wallRight.png");
        this.load.image("WallBottom", "assets/wallBottom.png");
        this.load.image("wallTop", "assets/wallTop.png");
        this.load.image("bg", "assets/bg.png");
    }
    //Create function for gameScene
    create() {
        this.floor = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        this.wallTop = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        this.wallBottom = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        this.wallLeft = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        this.wallRight = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        this.bg = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
        //Splitting the map string by into array variables
        let mapArr = map.split('.');
        //For each loop goes through each row of mapArr
        mapArr.forEach(row => {
            //Setting pixel value X to 0 when its a new row
            drawX = 0;
            //Goes through each variable in the row and creates image in its place
            for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                if (row.charAt(i) === '7') {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
                } else if (row.charAt(i) === '9') {
                    this.wallTop.create(drawX, drawY, "wallTop");
                } else if (row.charAt(i) === '8') {
                    this.wallBottom.create(drawX, drawY, "wallBottom");
                } else if (row.charAt(i) === '5') {
                    this.wallLeft.create(drawX, drawY, "wallLeft");
                } else if (row.charAt(i) === '6') {
                    this.wallRight.create(drawX, drawY, "wallRight");
                } else if (row.charAt(i) === '1') {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
                    //Creating player variables
                    //  this.player = this.add(drawX, drawY, "player");
                    // this.player.body.setGravityY(0);
                    // this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wallLeft);
                    //  this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wallRight);
                    //  this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wallTop);
                    //  this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wallBottom);
                    // this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
                    // this.player.score = 0;
                    // this.scoreText = this.add.text(0, 0, "Score: "+this.player.score, {
                    //  fill:"#000000",
                    //  fontSize:"20px",
                    //  fontFamily:"Arial Black"
                    // }).setScrollFactor(0).setDepth(200);
                } else {
                    this.bg.create(drawX, drawY, "bg");
                }
                //Add 16 each time a image is added (16by16 pixel images)
                drawX += 16
            }
            //Add 16 each time a new row is entered (16by16 pixel images)
            drawY += 16;
        });
    }
    //update function for gameScene
    update() {

    }

}
//END OF GAME SCENES

//Var config to create game screen
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 3000,
    height: 1500,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {
                y: 0
            },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

//Run actual game
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
//Create new screens and scenes
game.scene.add("load", loadScene);
game.scene.add("game", mainScene);
game.scene.add("end", endScene);
//start with this scene
game.scene.start("game");
```

I wanted to output the randomized dungeon created in 2D array format and returned as a string. I wanted to output it as images based on the values in the string.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? did I miss something? If so please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: No it did not work. I currently am using this code,   let config = {
   type: Phaser.AUTO,
        ...
   },
   scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
   }
  };
  //Create phaser game
  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
  
  function preload() {... But i would like to use the other code format if you have any ideas. When I tried your fix the map just wouldnt show up at all. Updated code is at https://replit.com/@JackF99/test-2d-array#script2.js.

Comment: The problem could be that in the code version, might not have the functions `preload`, `create` and `update` used in the _game-config_. Checkout the updated answer, or the  [official examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/scene-from-es6-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is not shown, because the GameScene is never loaded. Just some minor tweaks, are needed to make it visible. See below for details.

```js
    class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
        constructor(){
            // set the scene key name
            super('Game');
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    // add the scene
    game.scene.add('Game', GameScene);
    // start the scene, this key should be the same of the `constructor`
    game.scene.start('Game');
```

> **btw.:** for map's in phaser, you could use phaser's **TileMap**. checkout this [officials tutorials](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/tilemap), if you are interested.

A better solution might even be, to add all scenes into the `config` object, like so:

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 3000,
    height: 1500,
    ...    
    scene: [loadScene, mainScene, endScene]
 };
```

> **Info:** The first Scene in the list will be loaded, the other scenes are only started, if in their *config* the property `active` is set to `true`. Details to the [GameConfig documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.GameConfig).

Comment: Would you mind checking out my new post? Im using the format my teacher recently showed us but it wont work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185874/phaser-scene-will-not-boot-correctly-it-just-displays-a-empty-screen